# Using Form in Alertdialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create an object in body and use it in alertdialog, how should I do it? For example:

```
var form = Form(
);
********
return AlertDialog(
content: form,
),
```

The reason I want to do this is because when I try to use the buildForm structure outside the body it doesn't work. But I can't define it in the body because I want to use floating action button how can I solve it or is there a different way to solve it?

[image]

```
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    tooltip: "New ToDo",
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("New ToDo"),
            content: Container(
              child: Column(children: [
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    buildForm(_controllerTitle, "Title")
                  ],),
                ),
              ],),
            ),
            actions: [
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: What is `buildForm` in your case? Can you include that on quesiton

Comment: Are you asking for _controllerTitle, "Title"

Comment: nope, `buildForm` method. are you using any package or custom method it?

Comment: no any package etc. I dont use

Comment: I am not aware of this type  of `buildForm` exits

Comment: Got it, thanks for everything. I want to ask one more thing, is there a way to do something similar to this? I mean being able to enter textual content within a popup window how can I do that? If you have an answer about this in your mind, I would be very happy if you tell me from the answer the question option.

Comment: Yes you can create method to do something like this

Comment: what kind of structure? Is there a widget for this? I would also like to add that I can do this using a text field, but I don't know how to pass the "_controllerTitle" object to the text field. Do you have an idea? Also, since this structure is triggered by a floating action button, I can't do anything about it in the body.

Comment: Try below method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method  `buildForm` that will take a `TextEditingController` and `String`

```dart
  Widget buildForm(TextEditingController controller, String title) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(title), // or just use on input decoration
          TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Customize the way you want.
And can be use like

```dart
 buildForm(_controllerTitle, "Title"),
```

```dart
class _EXTTEstState extends State<EXTTEst> {
  Widget buildForm(TextEditingController controller, String title) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(title), // or just use on input decoration
          TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  final _controllerTitle = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        tooltip: "New ToDo",
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("New ToDo"),
                content: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Form(
                        // key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            buildForm(_controllerTitle, "Title"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i started getting these errors [image](https://i.imgur.com/gaJpAaI.png)

Comment: Not inside the Widget tree, inside the class

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/thaG5qv.png

Comment: You have already define `_controllerTitle`, remove this line

Comment: inside column the way you did for ` buildForm(_controllerTitle, "Title"),` , check more about [forms](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)  and [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)

Comment: It worked successfully, no errors! really thank you for everything